# Averaging column results and combing rows with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, database, csv, average

So I have two large csv files of data regarding road networks. The first file has 3 columns, count_point_id, road_name and all_motor_vehicles. The second, has CP_number, road_number and geometry.

In the first csv file, there are multiple vehicle counts for each count point ID [image: shown in picture]

My first question is how can I average the vehicle count in all the rows for a set count point id, and combine it into 1 single row? Some have 2 vehicle counts, some have 20.

Then, once that is done I need to combine the two tables, by matching up the count point numbers, as they are the same, giving me an average vehicle count for a set geometry. [image: This is the second table]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

1. `groupby`

   ```
   df = df.groupby(['count_point_id', 'road_name'], as_index=False).mean()

   df

      count_point_id road_name  all_motor_vehicles
   0              52     A3112               354.5
   ```
2. rename columns and `merge`

   ```
   df.merge(roads.set_axis(['count_point_id', 'road_name', 'geometry'], axis=1))

      count_point_id road_name  all_motor_vehicles    geometry
   0              52     A3112               354.5  SomeObject
   ```

---

#### Setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'count_point_id': [52, 52],
    'road_name': ['A3112', 'A3112'],
    'all_motor_vehicles': [315, 394]
})

roads = pd.DataFrame({
    'CP_Number': [52.],
    'RoadNumber': ['A3112'],
    'geometry': ['SomeObject']
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much that's perfect!!

Comment: Remember to click the ✅

Comment: I have done thank you! Is there any chance you could please take a look at the follow up question? I would be incredibly grateful! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66786572/data-points-from-csv-inside-set-areas-from-another-csv-file-using-geopandas